# adding user to group and detects the change without restart

Tags: user, user-groups

I want to add a user to a group using:

```
sudo gpasswd -a new_user existing_group
```

But it only takes effect when I restart my host. Is it possible to do that without restart action?

I am on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.edwards-research.com/2010/10/linux-refresh-group-membership-without-logging-out/

```
exec su -l $USER
```

Maybe?   Works for the current user, not sure if it refreshes other user memberships